# ListView with text and checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I used RelativeLayout for my ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="CheckBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my ListView code,

```
private void displayList(){
    ArrayList<String> diyListArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    diyListArray.add("1");
    diyListArray.add("2");
    diyListArray.add("3");
    diyListArray.add("4");
    diyListArray.add("5");
    diyListArray.add("6");
    diyListArray.add("7");
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.selectrow, R.id.test, diyListArray);
    diyList.setAdapter( listAdapter );
}
```

We can see here that I used ArrayAdapter with resource id of TextView.
I am able to display the checkboxes and their corresponding texts.

How can I get user selected texts from checkboxes?

Comment: you can try getting the item position of list view which is clicked!

Comment: Any sample code for that?

Comment: on what event you want to extract the text?

Comment: I want to extract the text on a bottom navigation select event, but it is another problem for me. So I plan to get the selected texts after click on each checkbox for testing purposes only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

Demo10.class:----

```
public class Demo10 extends AppCompatActivity implements Listener {

private ListView lv;
private boolean[] state_ = new boolean[4];
private String[] text_ = new String[4];


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo11);

    for(int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++) {
        state_[i] =  false;
        text_[i] = "text"+i;
    }

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(Demo10.this , this));// This includes a Listener that listens to onCheckBoxStateChanges.

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // used to handle ListView onItemClicks and how they should affect the corresponding checkBox
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            CheckBox cb = view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            cb.setChecked(!cb.isChecked());
            displayCheckBoxStateText();
        }
    });

}


private void displayCheckBoxStateText(){


    for(int i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++){
        Log.e("CheckBox", text_[i]+" : " + state_[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public void checkBox1(boolean state) {
    state_[0] =  state;
    displayCheckBoxStateText();

}

@Override
public void checkBox2(boolean state) {
    state_[1] = state;
    displayCheckBoxStateText();

}

@Override
public void checkBox3(boolean state) {
    state_[2] = state;
    displayCheckBoxStateText();

}

@Override
public void checkBox4(boolean state) {
    state_[3] = state;
    displayCheckBoxStateText();

}
}
```

ItemAdapter.class:-----

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Listener callback;

public ItemAdapter(Context c , Listener l) {
    mContext = c;
    callback = l;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return s.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CheckBox cb;
    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.demo10, null);
        }
    }
    cb = view.findViewById(R.id.cb);

    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    callback.checkBox1(isChecked);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    callback.checkBox2(isChecked);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    callback.checkBox3(isChecked);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    callback.checkBox4(isChecked);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    cb.setText(s[position]);
    return view;
}

private String[] s = {
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3",
        "test4"
};

}
```

Listener interface:----

```
public interface Listener {

public void checkBox1(boolean state);

public void checkBox2(boolean state);

public void checkBox3(boolean state);

public void checkBox4(boolean state);

}
```

demo10.xml:----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

demo11.xml:-----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv">
</ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make choice mode first

```
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

I am making a button by clicking on it you can retrieve all the items you checked

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    SparseBooleanArray checked = listview.getCheckedItemPositions();

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            selectedItems.add(listAdapter.getItem(position));
    }
}
```

here you get all the items checked in your selectedItems ArrayList.

Comment: Let me know if this works! else we can move for an alternate solution.

Comment: I added button on the UI but how can I add onClick listener on View? I am getting setOnCLickListener in View cannot be applied to ...

Comment: You can try one thing; make a custom adapter, and from there you can handle click listener on every checkbox item and get your text. If you find this good I will update the answer

Comment: Btw. I am able now to do bottomnavigation select event. Now I tried your solution in this issue but not working.

Comment: I also tried, list.getCheckedItemCount() and it returns 0.

Comment: Try these reference (here)[http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html] and (here)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sd0YBZ73nBo]

Comment: This answer is not specific to the question.

Comment: @Akshay, I followed your mysamplecode.com sample and got an error "Cannot resolve symbol countryList" on ArrayList<Country> countryList = dataAdapter.countryList;

Comment: DId you make a Country class?

Comment: Yes. I created a Country class. But on same file.

Answer (score 0):

You can override getView() of ArrayAdapter and handles views by yourself. Replace:

```
listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.selectrow, R.id.test, diyListArray);
```

with

```
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.selectrow, diyListArray){
        boolean[] checked = new boolean[diyListArray.size()];
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null) convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.selectrow, null);
            TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.test);
            CheckBox checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            textView.setText(getItem(position));
            checkBox.setChecked(checked[position]);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    checked[position] = !checked[position];
                    String msg = "Checked Item: ";
                    if(!checked[position]) msg = "Unchecked Item: ";
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg + getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    };
```

I have blog about ListView: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/

Hope that helps!